# Can anyone please explain why they multiply -7 by 2 and remove it from N^2?

Tags: logarithms

[image: Outlined solution unclear]

Can anyone please explain why they multiply -7 by 2 and remove it from N^2?

Comment: They? Who? What is your question?

Comment: If you check out the picture I linked, you'll see there is a solution in it. I am confused as to a step in the solution (picture is titled "Outlined solution unclear")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think they're doing: Making a variable substitution $N\mapsto \frac M2$ and then multiply on both sides by $2$. If we do that, we get
$$
0 = 2N^2 - 5N - 7\\
0 = 2\left(\frac M2\right)^2 - 5\frac M2 - 7\\
0 = \frac {M^2}2 - 5\frac M2 - 7\\
0 = M^2 - 5M - 14
$$
We can then solve and factor this in terms of $M$, and switch back $N$ via the reverse substitution $M\mapsto 2N$. Noticing that $14 = 7\cdot 2$ and $5 = 7-2$, we get:
$$
0 = M^2 - 5M - 14\\ 
0 = (M-7)(M+2)\\
0 = \left(2N - 7\right)\left(2N + 2\right)\\
0 = \left(2N - 7\right)\left(N + 1\right)
$$
where in the final line I factored out a factor $2$ from the last bracket and divided it away.

They did all of this while calling the intermediate variable $N$, *the same name* as the initial and final variable, which is just wrong. It's no wonder you got confused.

Besides, I don't see why you can't just apply the quadratic formula to $0 = 2N^2 - 5N - 7$ to directly obtain
$$
N = \frac{5\pm\sqrt{25 - 4\cdot 2\cdot (-7)}}{2\cdot 2}\\
= \frac{5\pm\sqrt{81}}{4}\\
= \frac{5\pm 9}{4}\\
= \frac72\text{ or }{-1}
$$
While this might arguably not be faster or easier, it's reasonably fast and easy. More importantly, though, I would say it's a lot easier to follow for everyone reading it, and you're not left wondering things like "Why did they do that? How did they know it would work? Is it allowed?"

Comment: Arthur, thank you so much, both for explaining their reasoning and for modifying the question to show the pic. It was my first time posting and I didn't see an option to include the picture otherwise :)